# Truncate table Dataverse

Tags: sql, sql-server, dataverse

I am trying to truncate a table in Dataverse, so I have installed SQL Server Management studio, selected my database, and ran the query `TRUNCATE TABLE tablename` However, I get the error:

```
Msg 40000, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'TRUNCATE' statement​ is not supported. Line:1, Position:1
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Connection to Dataverse is read-only

> The SQL connection provides read-only access to the table data of the
> target Dataverse environment thereby allowing you to execute SQL
> queries against the Dataverse data tables.

[Use SQL to query data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/dataverse-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks you for the answer... is there any way to truncate a table in Dataverse?

Comment: Not a dataverse expert, but a quick search turned up: https://blogs.perficient.com/2021/02/16/power-platform-dataverse-cds-bulk-record-deletion/